# Convert MonthName to month Number SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I currently need to convert month name to a number in order for me to write my code. My current parameter (StartMonth) has the coded "=dateadd("m",-1,dateserial(year(Today()),month(Today()),1))". In one of my fields, this gives me an output of (e.g 1-May-2017). I need to be able to extract the month name and have it converted to a month number. (From 1-May-2017(Current) -> 5(Desired output))

Comment: have you tried the month function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following should work:

```
=datepart("M",Parameters!DateParam.Value)
```

or

```
=datepart("M",Today())
```

and for you example

```
=datepart("M",cDate("1 May 2017"))
```

will return **5**.

**->** For required result, leave the `FORMAT` option blank

Comment: imo, its best to always use the full term when specifying datepart.   eg:=datepart("Month",Today()) which makes it absolutely explicit what you mean and specifically for Month (m) to avoid confusion over minute (mi)

Comment: @Trubs, did u tried that? I believe using "Month" is not valid.

Comment: Thanks @ImRaN.   I'm an idiot. (note to self - understand the question and test your work before you post it publicly!),   my comment relates to  TSQL (and even that was wrong), the correct syntax (for TSQL) is    `=DatePart(Month,GetDate())`,

Comment: In a (poor) attempt to add _some_ value to the discussion, you could also use `=Month(Today())`

Comment: there u go. last one is perfect.